# Retrieving RTSP/RTP Timestamps

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, rtsp

This is an update to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590264/modifying-ffmpeg-and-opencv-source-code-to-capture-the-rtp-timestamp-for-each-pa). I am able to get the RTP timestamps by using ffmpeg and opencv currently, however, I am trying to actually get the timestamp at which the frame was captured. I did a work around to try find the time at which the frame was captured (code is in python).

```
seconds_before_frame = cap.getRTPTimeStampSeconds()
fractionofseconds_before_frame = cap.getRTPTimeStampFraction()
ret, frame = cap.read()
seconds_after_frame = cap.getRTPTimeStampSeconds()
fractionofseconds_after_frame = cap.getRTPTimeStampFraction()
```

By doing this I found that the time captured was off by `0.02359296` seconds and sometimes `0.2359296` seconds, that's a lot more than I had expected.

I saw a work around with trying to get the timestamp of the frame by using AVFormatContext which I didn't really understand through the priv_data.

```
AVPacket* packet;
av_read_frame(formatCtx, packet);
RTSPState* rtspState = formatCtx->priv_data; 
RTPDemuxContext *rtpdemux = rtspState->rtsp_streams[packet->stream_index]->transport_priv;
```

as well as

```
RTSPState *state = _formatCtx->priv_data; 
RTSPStream *stream = state->rtsp_streams[0]; 
RTPDemuxContext *demux = stream->transport_priv; 
demux→timestamp
```

I'd like to ask how can we call AVFormatContext from C++ side, is it through `av_read_frame` ? Is it possible to use python bindings or `VideoCapture` already wraps ffmpeg so there is no need to use `av_read_frame` but just call `VideoCapture`?